# Android Sinch SDK disable history

Tags: android, sinch

Android Sinch SDK returns chat history, but I don't need it because I'm getting data from api, is there any way to disable history in sinch?
I've searched for the answer in sinch docs and samples, but didn't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sinch stores messages for 30 days to make sure they are delivered to all of a user's devices (ex: phone and tablet). When you uninstall and re-install an app, Sinch treats it as a new device for that user and delivers the last 30 days of messages.

If you don't like this behavior, you can easily filter the incoming messages for duplicates, since each message has a unique id.

Comment: The thing is that i've already filter messages, but it causes extra time for compares and so on, so i wanted to just it disable it fully, but thanks for the answer =)